# How to fix class variables/constants as dictionaries get overwritten?

Tags: python, class, variables

I am new to python and trying to use default values and customise them for a class instance.

So in this example I am defining a `DEFAULT_STRING` and a `DEFAULT_SETTINGS` variable, which can be customise using `customize()` and should be resetted to default on `reset()`.

This is working fine for `DEFAULT_STRING`. But somehow `customize()` is overriding the `DEFAULT_SETTINGS` dictionary.

```
class TestClass:
  DEFAULT_STRING = 'default string'

  DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
  }

  def __init__(self):
    self.reset()

  def customize(self):
    self.string = 'custom string'
    self.settings['key2'] = 'CUSTOM VALUE'

  def reset(self):
    self.string = TestClass.DEFAULT_STRING
    self.settings = TestClass.DEFAULT_SETTINGS

test = TestClass()
test.customize()

print(test.DEFAULT_STRING) # default string
print(test.string) # custom string 
print(test.DEFAULT_SETTINGS) # {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'CUSTOM VALUE'} 
print(test.settings) # {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'CUSTOM VALUE'} 

test.reset()

print(test.DEFAULT_STRING) # default string
print(test.string) # default string 
print(test.DEFAULT_SETTINGS) # {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'CUSTOM VALUE'} 
print(test.settings) # {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'CUSTOM VALUE'}
```

I am pretty sure that there is a very simple solution, but somehow I'm stuck between the lines...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to take a copy of the defaults in the `reset` method -- at the moment your settings field is a direct reference to the defaults. You can do this with e.g. `self.settings = dict(TestClass.DEFAULT_SETTINGS))`

Comment: Thanks @JoeHalliwell, this worked so far! Is this the best way to achieve this? Or do you have any better option in mind?

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand what

```
self.settings = TestClass.DEFAULT_SETTINGS
```

does.

The statement makes `settings` a name in the namespace of the instance.
And it points to the very same object that is pointed to by the `DEFAULT_SETTINGS` name in the class' namespace.

That means the statement does not create a new object.

Note: that happens for `self.string` also. But in that case, `self.string` is a string, which is immutable. That means that when you assign a new value to the same name, a new object is created.

Let's go through an example:

```
>>> class C:
...  S = 'asdasd'
... 
>>> o = C()
>>> o.s = C.S
>>> o.s
'asdasd'
>>> o.s is C.S
True
>>> o.s = 'pasdpdspa'
>>> o.s is C.S
False
>>> o.s = C.S
>>> C.S = 'popopo'
>>> o.s
'asdasd'
```

On the other hand, the dictionary is mutable and gets modified in-place.

So, as suggested in the comments, in order to make it work you need to copy such dictionary, e.g. with

```
self.settings = dict(TestClass.DEFAULT_SETTINGS))
```

or even better with

```
from copy import deepcopy
self.settings = deepcopy(self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS)
```

Note: the latter is needed if the dictionary is nested. `dict` makes a shallow copy only, so it would not work in all cases.

Let's show it with an example:

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2: {21: 'abc', 22: 'def'}}
>>> d
{1: 10, 2: {21: 'abc', 22: 'def'}}
>>> d2 = dict(d)
>>> d is d2
False
>>> d[2] is d2[2]
True
>>> d2[2] = 99
>>> d
{1: 10, 2: {21: 'abc', 22: 'def'}}
>>> d2 = dict(d)
>>> d2[2][21] = 99
>>> d
{1: 10, 2: {21: 99, 22: 'def'}}
```

whereas

```
>>> d = {1:10, 2: {21: 'abc', 22: 'def'}}
>>> d2 = deepcopy(d)
>>> d2[2] is d[2]
False
>>> d2[2][21] = 99
>>> d
{1: 10, 2: {21: 'abc', 22: 'def'}}
```

Note2: as you may notice, the name 
DEFAULT_SETTINGS in the class' namespace can be reached via the instance, i.e.

```
self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS
```

instead of

```
TestClass.DEFAULT_SETTINGS
```

I suggest to do some research on Python's immutable and mutable types, in-place modification, namespaces and name resolution, inheritance, etc

Comment: Thank you for clarifying... that was exactly what I thought is happening behind the scenes, but didn't know how to solve... ;-)

Comment: I am calling the `customize()` method in a loop and somehow it only worked for the first iteration. In the following iterations the problem occurs again. With `deepcopy` it's working fine now. Is this the best and only solution?

Comment: Uhm.. weird. Copying things around is never a good sign. Maybe you can find a better pattern for your algorithm

Comment: Do you know why the problem only occurs for dicts and not for the string `DEFAULT_STRING`? Should I rather store the default values like `DEFAULT_KEY1 = ...`, `DEFAULT_KEY2 = ...`?

Comment: Done. Have a look! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me out - even if I changed the approach, it's important to understand!

Comment: I have added a further note :)